# Resizing polygon features in ArcGIS Desktop based on attribute value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I have a polygon dataset representing all the municipalities within a certain county.

Is there is a way to resize each feature in the dataset based on an attribute value?

Obviously, the features are naturally sized by their area, but I'd like to be able to resize them by - for example - population or median income for visual effect.

I know how to add and use the Scale tool on the Editor toolbar; this function is exactly what I want to do (i.e., resize / scale while retaining the shape), but I wonder if there isn't a more precise way to do this (i.e., based on the value of a certain attribute).

I know it's possible to do what I ask by selecting each feature individually then setting the scaling factor to whatever attribute value, but I'm curious if there isn't a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Rather unusual way to show pattern. Anyway you might consider using buffer tool, note buffer can be both positive and negative. A bit of math involved though, if you want shrinking/expanding reflected in shape area

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons) question has some good solutions for `polygon offsetting`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

Cartogram geoprocessing tool v2

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15638

How to make area cartogram maps in ArcGIS

http://www.gislounge.com/how-to-make-area-cartogram-maps-in-arcgis/

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're after is the ability to create non-contiguous cartograms. I found kind of a clunky workflow which is not exactly scalable to many features, but it worked for my case with just a handful. I used [representation symbology in ArcMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/what-are-representations-.htm) to resize polygons based on a ratio. In my case, I wanted to represent the Colorado River apportionment to each of seven river basin states and Mexico, but I wanted to resize each state and Mexico proportionate to the percent of that state's allotment compared to the state with the maximum allotment (California). For instance, California is shown represented at its normal size, while Wyoming, which gets 24% of California's apportion, is shown at 24% its size. [image: Representation Symbology applied to states showing percent of Colorado River apportioned to each state compared to the state with the maximum allotment (California).]

The representation symbology is stored with the feature in a gdb, and can be imported to ArcGIS Pro. When added to a map, the representation symbology is accessed from the Symbology tab. However, the representation symbology is uneditable in Pro as discussed in this [Pro Help topic](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/help/mapping/layer-properties/draw-layers-with-representations.htm). [image]

The tool cited by artwork21 is great for creating contiguous cartograms ([here's the direct link](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d348614c97264ae19b0311019a5f2276)).

There is an [ArcGIS Pro idea](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/cartograms-required/idc-p/1134413#M18333) posted for the ability to create non-contiguous cartograms if you'd like to give it a vote!